# Execute NodeMouseClick no works

Tags: c#, treeview

Into `load_form` I want to run programmatically `NodeMoseClick` event of Microsoft Tree View like:

```
  var selectedNode = tvProjectList.SelectedNode;
  TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs treeNodeMouseClickEventArgs = new TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(selectedNode, MouseButtons.Left, 1, 1, 1);
  tvProjectList.Select();

     tvProjectList.NodeMouseClick += tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick;
```

When I debug code and hits this line and I press continue it just don't execute method: `tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick`.

Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

With the following line NodeMouseClick.

```
tvProjectList.NodeMouseClick += tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick;
```

To actually call the event you have to do something like this:

```
var selectedNode = tvProjectList.SelectedNode;
TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs treeNodeMouseClickEventArgs = new TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(selectedNode, MouseButtons.Left, 1, 1, 1);
tvProjectList.Select();

tvProjectList.NodeMouseClick += tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick;

tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick(this, treeNodeMouseClickEventArgs);
```

One thing to keep in mind is, that you actually might have a `tvProjectList.SelectedNode` that is `null`, since you just initialized.